# How to call function on Return true

Tags: javascript

i have following code which return a popup message for reload page or not.
I have to perform a function when user click on "Reload page" and remain on same page when user click on "Not Reload".

```
window.onbeforeunload = function()
{
    return "";
};
```

How can i do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<script>
  var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
  var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compatable

  myEvent(chkevent, function (e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
    var confirmationMessage = ' '; // a space
    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
    return confirmationMessage;
  });
</script>
```

Fetched from [this](http://devzone.co.in/show-confirmation-box-page-refresh-page-unload-using-javascript/) article. This is their [demo](http://lab.devzone.co.in/confirmation-box-using-javascript/index.html)

Comment: i want to perform a function when it return true

Comment: This can not be done (thankfully). You can only return the message to show 'on close'.

Comment: What is the problem? when reload, it asks if wants to reload or not to. On closing, it prompts appropriately!

Comment: nothing problem but i want to perform function on return true.
how to do this?

Comment: If by "return true" you mean "yes, I want to close the window", then again, you simply can't. There is no way of executing code 'on close' with modern browsers other than to return the message you want to show the user.

What is the purpose of the method you want to call? If it is 'save on exit' type functionality you are after, there are many other ways to do this (like 'auto save' on change or after x mins of inactivity, etc).